# Location of /root/ on Windows 10 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 - the insider preview edition. Windows terminals are however are sort of cumbersome to use if one is used to Ubuntu's terminal. I was wondering if there is a way to access the Ubuntu filesystem from Windows so that I can do the development in some other editor and run the code from Ubuntu-bash ?

Comment: Nowadays, Windows supports multiple Linux distributions in the same machine. The root location vay depending on the distribution you are using. You can find them into the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages`. For Ubuntu 18.04, it is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`

Answer (score 6):

Any terminal program that can open a Windows command prompt should be able to run bash (bash.exe launches the Windows Linux Subsytem), so you don't have to be stuck with command.exe.

Conemu (mentioned by @anotherfred) or Cmder are some of the fan favorites. You can also use Powershell if you like that.

You can access your Windows files from WSL at /mnt/c (and /mnt/d if you have a d: drive, etc). That works relatively well if you want to do command line stuff and still access the files using your favorite Windows editor.

You can see your [WSL file system](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/) from Windows at:

```
%LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs
```

though I wouldn't mess with it from within Windows.

**/root** would be under

```
%LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs\root
```

and

**/home** would be under

```
%LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs\home
```

These two are mounted separately so that they are not deleted when you remove WSL.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 versions released since the end of 2017 (including the Fall Creators Update and Windows Insiders Builds 17063+) supports multiple linux distributions running on the same machine. In consequence, WSL must store the root filesystem for each distribution in a different location.

The root filesystem is **not located** anymore at

```
%LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs
```

---

### New location of the filesystem folders

Each linux distribution installed from the Windows Store stores the root filesystem in a different folder at

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\<distro folder>\LocalState
```

The `<distro folder>` vary from one distribution to the other. For instance, the following are the `<distro folder>` in my test computer:

- Ubuntu 16.04 : `CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu16.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`
- Ubuntu 18.04 : `CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`
- Debian : `TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_76v4gfsz19hv4`
- Kali linux: `KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg`

If you wanna access the **root** or the **home** filesystems, you must use the appropriated folders. For instance, to go to the folders for the KaliLinux, you must go to:

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg\rootfs   # root
%LocalAppData%\Packages\KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg\home     # home
```

---

### Obtaining the path using lxRunOffline

[LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) is a tool to manage WSL linux distributions. It can be used to install or move a WSL distribution to any folder of your computer.

You can use `lxRunOffline get-dir` to obtain the path of the installation folder. The *root* is in the `rootfs` sub-folder.

```
C:\> lxrunoffline list
Ubuntu-18.04
ubuntu-copy

C:\> lxrunoffline get-dir -n Ubuntu-18.04
C:\Users\nnn\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState

C:\> lxrunoffline get-dir -n ubuntu-copy
d:\wsl\installed\ubuntu-copy
```

---

### Obtaining the path Programmatically

If you are interested, you can obtain the path using a program. The information about the installed distributions and their configuration is stored in the Windows Registry.

You can check the information using the `regedit` and the following path:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss
```

There is all the configuration of the diverse distributions you have installed. For instance, You can use Powershell to obtain the information of the base path for the default distribution.

```
$WSLREGKEY="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss"
$WSLDEFID=(Get-ItemProperty "$WSLREGKEY").DefaultDistribution
$DISTROPATH=(Get-ItemProperty "$WSLREGKEY\$WSLDEFID").BasePath
echo "the filesystems are located at $DISTROPATH"
```

To check the filesystems for all your installed distributions, you can use Powershell too.

```
(Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath}) | select DistributionName,BasePath
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way round: bash is accessing the windows filesystem which you will find at `/mnt/c`. Your files are (should be) in your windows filesystem and you can edit them as normal.

If you simply dislike the terminal interface, try something like conemu (https://conemu.github.io/). It's a convenient and pretty interface for command shell, powershell or whatever shell you like.